Laravel Herd: upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream
I do have Laravel Herd (1.6) installed and Xdebug configured based on Herd's documentation and I'm using PhpStorm as my IDE.
Whenever I run a project endpoint (whether from browser or via API client), I always end up with this error (from NGINX logs)

This error occurs only when my PhpStorm is listening for PHP Debug Connections, but everything works if I turn it off.
Has anyone bumped into this issue before?
I tried adding the following Xdebug config in my php.ini but it doesn't help.
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.client_port=9003


No answer by Laravel Herd developers? Shameful. Having same type of issues. It wont even connect to Mongo. Same error.
